# SlickGrid Custom Filter

Tags: jquery, search, filter, slickgrid

Searching through here and it doesn't seem to find the answer.

I setup a pretty complicated grid with SlickGrid.

The search function is in a custom toolbar. Which I wire it up the call to the grid function.

for example:

[HTML]

```
 <input name='name' id='id' class='searchable'>
```

[JS]

```
$('.searchable').on('change' , function() {
     var searchTerm = {};     
         searchTerm[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();

     dataview.setFilterArgs(searchTerm);
     dataview.refresh();
});
```

And I can see the argument getting pass to the custom filter

```
var customFilter = function(item, args) {
    ***$.each(args , function(key , val) {
        if (val!=='' && val!==null) {
           return (item[key] == val);
        }
    });***
return true;
}
```

[!] the problem is when you are inside the $.each , if you do "return" it only skip the loop. But there is nothing return to outside of the function.

**BUT NOTHING HAPPENS ON THE GRID. NOTHING GET FILTERED**

Here is my setup

```
dataview = new Slick.Data.DataView();
grid = new Slick.Grid(grid_id , dataview , columns , options);
grid.selectionModel(new Slick.RowSelectionModel());

grid.init();

dataview.beginUpdate();
dataview.setItems(gridData);
dataview.setFilter(customFilter);
dataview.endUpdate();
```

I have been following the two filter examples from github. But I can't see any different apart from this

if I init the data view with

```
dataview = new Slick.Data.DataView({inlineFilters: true});
```

I get an error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Undefined label '_coreloop' (slick.dataview.js line: 639)

Try to read the code but lack of comments ... so I really don't know what is the problem.

Anyone got the similar issue?

Comment: Is this your base example? http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-header-row.html

Comment: http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html

Comment: What kind of filter search are you trying to do? The link to the example I gave which is the one I always use, is embedding a search field on top of each column, so it's easy to filter with. The example you gave is for a specific column and is different approach, what exactly are you trying to filter?

Comment: My bad :) found the reason. It was the filter function. I was using $.each(args , function(key, val) { return val; }); //but nothing actually return. Silly me! Thanks for replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call this function if you declared the dataView and columnFilters as global variables:

```
function SetfilterOnGrid(SearchPhrase) {
    columnFilters = {"1": SearchPhrase};
    dataView.refresh();
}
```

The number "1" is the column ID the SearchPhrase is the phrase you are searching in the Grid

as for clearing the filters you can use this function:

```
function ClearFilterOnGrid()
{
    columnFilters = {};
    dataView.refresh();
}
```